# How to make text box scrolling only vertically in Corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to include a text box in my app in which do not need horizontal scrolling. How can i do this in corona?

```
local sugg_field = native.newTextBox( 40, 155, 240, 150)
sugg_field.isEditable = true
sugg_field.font = native.newFont("PTSans-Regular", 17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isEditable property might be interfering with it. Also, things are not always the same on the corona emulator and an actual device. Try putting it onto a device and testing it. Link to similar question on corona forums:  http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/32985-nativenewtextbox-multiline-functionality-bugbroke-text-wrapping/